# Using kexec --load-panic to reboot if file system is corrupted

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have a device which loads a small 'safe mode' Yocto image from coreboot, then selects a larger image to load, and performs a kexec to load that image. Typically this works, but in rare cases the target image's file system has been corrupted and kernel panics on boot.

Since the device will eventually be deployed into locations that are difficult to access, I was hoping to find a way to recover from any kernel panic without having to physically reboot the device.

To fix this, I added an init script using "init=/sbin/init.sh" in the kexec command line when the new kernel is loaded, and I added a recovery kernel load using "kexec --load-panic" in the init script on the 2nd file system. This method successfully recovers kernel panics that happen late in the boot process, but I encountered a file system which was trashed in a particular way so that the kernel panic would occur before the init script gets launched. Since the init script isn't executed, the panic kernel never gets loaded, and the device must be power cycled.

To fix this, I tried adding the recovery kernel into the initial small kernel loaded by coreboot, but it appears to only handle kernel panics that occur before the "kexec --exec" command loads the new kernel.

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to solve this. For example, I could add validation before I kexec to the new image. I currently check that the file system can be mounted, that its kernel file and the init script are present. If anyone knows which other files are necessary to get to the init script, I could add them to my validation.

Alternatively, is there a way to load the new kernel and kexec to it with the recovery kernel "--load-panic" parameter already loaded?

I tried putting both the kexec --load and --load-panic in the same line, but that doesn't work.

Any recommendation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why is watchdog not an option here ?

Comment: Actually it might be a good idea. I hadn't considered it before because the hang occurs so early in the boot process (between the kexec and the init script). I wonder if it's possible to start a watchdog in the safe kernel with a long enough timeout that it can survive the kexec to the new kernel? Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: If hardware watchdog (your pimic might have a WD in it self) is feasible then you may feed the watchdog at the last stage of your bootloader or safe kernel with appropriately long bite time and then feed and reconfigure it again once the primary kernel is booted.